# How to reverse a sentence?

Tags: r, reverse

I want a function that takes a string (NOT a vector) and reverses the words in that string.

For example,

```
rev_sentence("hi i'm five")
## [1] "five i'm hi"
```

I have a function that reverses individual characters, but not something that will reverse a string that's essentially a sentence.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In `R`, We can use `strsplit` to split at one or more spaces and then reverse the elements and `paste` it together

```
sapply(strsplit(str1, "\\s+"), function(x) paste(rev(x), collapse=" "))
#[1] "five i'm hi"
```

If there is only a single string, then

```
paste(rev(strsplit(str1, "\\s+")[[1]]), collapse= " ")
#[1] "five i'm hi"
```

---

In `Python`, the option would be to `split` and `join` after reversing (`[::-1]`)

```
" ".join("hi i'm five".split()[::-1])
#"five i'm hi"
```

Or use the `reversed`

```
" ".join(reversed("hi i'm five".split()))
#"five i'm hi"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "hi i'm five"
```

Comment: Just so I'm understanding -- strsplit() returns a list, so really we're only calling function(x) ONCE on a vector containing "hi" "i'm" "five". Hence, the entire thing gets reversed. Is this correct?

Comment: @Jake You are right that `strsplit` returns a `list` of single vector i.e. length 1.  In the first case, we assume that if there are many strings, then it will a `list` of  `vector` ie. length more than 1.  That is the reason to loop through the `list` with `sapply` and get the reverse.  In the second case, the `list` is converted to `vector` by extracting the first element i.e. `[[1]]` and then apply the `rev` directly on the `vector`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar answer, but using `tidyverse` functions:

```
x <- paste("hi i'm", c("five", "six", "seven"))

library(stringr)
purrr::map_chr(x, ~ str_flatten(rev(str_split_1(.x, "\\s")), " "))
# "five i'm hi"  "six i'm hi"   "seven i'm hi"
```